# Adding placeholders in drupal-8 with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, drupal-8

I am developing a drupal 8 website. I wanted to add placeholders to my forms. Most modules about placeholders are in drupal 7 only. I tried the simple solution of adding placeholders with jquery on my theme's script.js like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#edit-field-location-value").attr("placeholder","all locations");
});
```

It worked wonderfull in firefox but not in chrome. Anyone knows how to make jquery work on chrome?

Comment: This looks like it should work in Chrome. Basic question, but did you clear your CSS/JS cache (in the Drupal admin) when before testing?

Comment: @Joni H         Yes,  I cleared the cache